# Two different fonts with two different baselines

Tags: fonts, baseline

I am mixing two (really, three) fonts together to get as close to a 'natural writing' experience for my students in slides that I produce.  There are good reasons to have the writing be as natural as possible (read: hard to read so students focus more intently on what they are reading).  I've managed to get all of the text to appear correctly: handwriting fonts show up correctly and math handwriting fonts show up correctly.

But the problem is that the GFS Neohellenic font is consistently placed lower than the Tillana and VAG-HandWritten fonts.  For example,

```
\documentclass[12 pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}

% Tillana is a free font by the Indian Type Foundry, available at:
% https://github.com/itfoundry/tillana/
% VAG Handwritten is a free font by VAG Design, available at:
% https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/VAG-HandWritten

\setsansfont{VAG-HandWritten}[Scale=1.35]
\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath}[Scale=.9]
\setmathfont[range={"03C0, "2013-"2014, "2018-"201A, "201C-"201E, "2021-"2022,
                    "2026, "2030, "2039-"203A, "2044, "20AC, "20BA, "20BD,
                    "2113, "2122, "2126, "212E, "2202, "2206, "220F, "2211,
                    "2212, "2215, "221A, "221E, "222B, "2246, "2260, "2264,
                    "2265, "25CA}
            ]{Tillana-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{Latin,latin,num}
            ]{tillana-semibold.ttf}[Scale=1.35]
\setmathfont[range={"00-"FF,
                    up/{Latin,latin,Greek,greek},
                    \increment}
            ]{VAG-HandWritten}[Scale=1.35]
\setmathfont[range=up/num
            ]{tillana-regular.ttf}[Scale=1.1]

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[plain,t]
       \[x\in X\]
       \[X\cap Y\]

    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

The intersection symbol and the element-of symbol are from GFS Neohellenic and don't match well with the heights of the other characters, which are VAG-HandWritten characters.

My feeling is that I can globally change the baseline for the Neohellenic font, but all the things I've tried from various posts don't pan out.

Also, this code does compile on my end in TeXpad, but I am not sure how to check that it compiles well here, so my apologies if you can't get it to work. If you can't, please let me know.